# flutter: "fatal error: module 'location' not found" Xcode cannot found modules

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I tried using the geolocator to get the current position, but Xcode (on M1 Mac/ arm64 ) was unable to detect the module. After some research, I simply changed the plugin and integrated the recommended pub locator. After that, however, the same error still occurs. This module is also not found.

```
↳
    objc[7998]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1eab43130) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1080f02c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[7998]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1eab43180) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1080f0318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/campermike/Documents/projects/cnow/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:18:9: fatal error: module 'location' not found
    @import location;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar error recently so follow my approach if you want save your time.
You need to `crate new project with same bundle id in your m1 Mac machine and just replace your codes & ios & Android mandatory files. Because all errors are architecture related.`

But before this please do following things:

1.Remove pub cache.
2.Flutter clean
3.Remove xcode derived data.